# How can I use like with float numbers in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, floating-point, numbers, precision

I have the following problem in my sqlite database there are values stored and for some purposes I need to remove entries. 
But before I need to get the id for the rows which I would like to remove. To get the id tried to use the following query:

```
select commonid from TestData where coordinate_x=5.707523 and coordinate_y=6.693941;
```

The result is zero, because the value for coordinate_y is 6.693940. Therefore I was thinking to use like to get the right result. It does not matter, because the values do not difference only in the first two digits after the comma. I tried:

```
select commonid from TestData where coordinate_x=5.707523 and coordinate_y LIKE "6.69394%";
```

This failed either and the result was zero.

I figured out in the internet that I could use * instead of %.

```
select commonid from TestData where coordinate_x=5.707523 and coordinate_y LIKE "6.69394*";
```

Unfortunately this did not work too.

So how can I use like or any other command to solve this problem?

Comment: Well if you're playing with numbers, use numbers method... for example if you don't mind the digits after the 2 first ones, you could round, or select between ranges... You could also cast your field to nvarchar in your where clause, but that will proabbly be very slow if you've got a lot of records...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sqlite> .schema t
CREATE TABLE t (f double);
sqlite> select * from t;
1.23456789
2.23456789
3.23456789
sqlite> select * from t where f = 1.23456789;
1.23456789
sqlite> select * from t where f like '1.23456789';
1.23456789
sqlite> select * from t where f like '1.234%';
1.23456789
sqlite> select * from t where f like '_.23456789';
1.23456789
2.23456789
3.23456789
```

Comment: Interesting this works in sqlite, but then is this portable SQL?

Comment: I tried it now in sqlitestudio, where I'm firstly trying the queries and it is not working. Only if I do `like '6.%`, then I'll get a result. Otherwise I get only 0 rows affected.

Comment: I'm sorry, now it is working. It seems that I transposed numbers and therefore it was not working. The interesting thing is only, that the used queries are copied from sqlitestudio.

Comment: Note that this is going to have to convert the entire column to a string type for this to work, and thus ignore indices.  Depending on other operations performed on the values first (and potentially some hardware-specific settings), exact comparisons of doubles have problems (ie, `.1` can't be exactly represented in floating point); this is why, near universally, floating point values are compared against an epsilon (range) of values.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Very true. But the question was not if `LIKE` is recommended but why it doesn't work (it does).

Comment: The questions was not only related to `LIKE`. I asked the following: So how can I use like or any other command to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it would be smarter (and probably faster) to do

```
SELECT commonid FROM TestData WHERE coordinate_x=5.707523 AND
    ABS(coordinate_y-6.693945)<0.000005;
```

or

```
SELECT commonid FROM TestData WHERE coordinate_x=5.707523 AND
    coordinate_y BETWEEN 6.69394 AND 6.69395;
```

Comment: Er, given the way that floating-point values tend to work, getting an exact comparison (`=`) is unlikely to select a result.  Also, when dealing with imprecise values, the use of `BETWEEN` [should generally be avoided](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (the post is about timestamps and SQL Server, but the principle applies in general).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Why in hell should `BETWEEN` be avoided with `FLOAT`? Also, why is using `LIKE` with `FLOAT` a good idea??? Because exact comparison is unlikely to happen, I suggested two methods of getting a number in an interval.

Comment: Oh no, I think using LIKE is a terrible idea too. Your exact comparison is `coordinate_x = 5.707523`.  My personal opinion is that BETWEEN should be removed from the standard, because it promotes thinking about ranges (especially for variable/im-precise types) the wrong way.  Granted, when dealing with an epsilon it should give correct results (although the two statements you give are _not_ equivalent); however, I feel like the use of `BETWEEN` here disguises the fact that's what you're going for.  Although some smart optimizers may specifically look for epsilons (common situation)...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Two statements I gave are not equivalent if your thinking about `FLOAT` precision limits (53 bit in SQLite). This situation, which must always be avoided, is not the question here. If I did `<=0.00001` they would become same, but effective difference is below `0.00000000000001`...

Comment: Er, `ABS(coordinate_y - 6.69394) <= 0.00001`  is equivalent to `coordinate_y BETWEEN 6.69393 AND 6.69395` (you need to change the range to `.000005`, and move the offset that much too).  And unless the value used for comparison in `coordinate_x = 5.707523` was grabbed from the table itself, you're _not_ guaranteed to get any rows; displays often round floating-point to some precision (5 or 6 places, usually), and floating-point math is often performed at a higher bit-count (leading to slightly different final values).  If you use `=` with floats/doubles, it's almost _never_ going to work.

Comment: I ignored `coordinate_x` at all - I agree with you, exact match with floating point is not an working solution. Now, I must insist that `ABS(coordinate_y - 6.69394) <= 0.00001` is equivalent to `coordinate_y BETWEEN 6.69393 AND 6.69395` - without any modification.

Comment: ... yes, now read the `BETWEEN` statement you have in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try treating as character

```
select commonid from TestData 
where coordinate_x=5.707523 
and Cast(coordinate_y as Char(100)) LIKE "6.69394%";
```

Comment: The numbers are stored as `REAL` and not as CHAR. It is not working. Only the following is working, but this do not consider the digits after the dot. `select commonid from TestData where coordinate_x=5.707523 and Cast(coordinate_y as CHAR(100)) LIKE '6.%';`

Comment: @IrgendwPointer Do you realize that using `LIKE` will implicitly cast your `REAL` numbers into `TEXT`?